# Is there a way to easily make 3d models and textures for people with no prior experience?

Tags: textures, 3d-modeling

I want to make a game, but I need assets. I am wondering if I should make them by myself even though I never made any textures or 3d models before. Are there technologies that allow you to easily make them? What would you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most definitely do this, there are so many great tutorials and books for about every kind of modeling software out there. YouTube, Blender LinkedIn Learning, Pluralsight ect…

I and many others are always browsing and for and buying unique art and models to use in creations. you can then create a sight and or find all the good sites that you can place your content on and they will keep it up and selling for a small cut of profits. Just to name a couple [Turbo Squid](https://www.turbosquid.com/), and [GameDevMarket](https://www.gamedevmarket.net/) pretty good options they have pretty wide global advertising ect. people are always browsing for unique stuff whether free or paid. Same with the Unity asset store or unreal engine marketplace those are also great spots to put art and models for creators to buy.

as far as different software options. that will be personal preference but I enjoy working with blender, probuilder in unity, gimp, cinema 4d is pretty great also. But id also get the trials and tutotorials to get some experience with some mainstream stuff like Maya, mudbox ect..

Dive in and make some good stuff and you will live the dream ;)

Comment: I am wondering if I really can since my drawing skills are kinda limited. Also, I have no idea how I can create textures for complex 3d models.

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not a specialist in any aspect of the visual part of game development but I figured if all I did was copy others' assets then I would never learn to model or animate so I took up blender. If I were you that's what I would do. Download blender and take it from there, it's free and it'll teach you the basics of 3D modelling and animation.

Comment: Can you sell your game if you do that though?

Comment: If you make models using Blender then they're legally your assets I believe so as long as your game engine allows you you can sell it.

Comment: But you're suggesting to copy people's assets, right? What do you mean by that? Just load and save?

Comment: No I'm suggesting creating your own assets from scratch in blender.

Comment: Ah, wait, I reread the answer. Is using Blender beginner-friendly? Isn't it just like any other modelling software?

Comment: Yes it's just like any other software but it's very popular so there's an abundance of tutorials.

Comment: Are there tutorials that show you how to do armors? And what about texturing?

Comment: Look on youtube

Answer (score 1):

I like the procedural approach more, I suggest Houdini or the Grasshopper plugin for Rhino, if you need more refined meshes that need hand modeling, you can polish using zBrush. It will take you longer to learn but you will have a powerful toolset that lets you iterate your geometry just by adjusting some sliders. For texturing I recommend Substance Painter as it is also procedural. There are plenty of tutorials and if you come from a programming background everything will just click, if you don't what you'll learn can definetely be applied to any kind of software development, so in any case is a win win if you go with proceduralism.